# Name for the cognitive bias of seeming to not need something when you have it, but needing it when you don't?

Tags: expressions

An example of what I'm talking about is buying a snow blower because the past few winters have been very snowy, only to find that the next several winters after buying have hardly any snow, i.e. "it stopped snowing because I bought a snow blower".

Another example is finding yourself often carrying an umbrella just in case it rains, but forgetting it once it actually does rain, i.e. "it rained because I forgot my umbrella today".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a classic falacy refered to as **[post hoc ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc)**.  It is Latin for

> after which, therefore because of which

If you do a rain dance over and over, sooner or later (unless you live somewhere perpetually arid) it will rain.  The dance did not *cause* the rain. Sooner or later it rains, whether you dance or not.

In virtualy every field of occurance, sooner or later there is a pattern (snow or lack thereof, rain or lack thereof). What makes you thinks your action (as opposed to the opposite action of your neighbor) is the controlling factor. And why do you think the snow/rain gods pay any attention to you at all?

Answer (score 1):

One's cognitive bias is often not perceived, and the belief that 'fate is against me' is a belief in what's called ['Sod's law'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod%27s_law), in the UK at least.

Being 'mocked by fate' adds personification.